# How to sort 2 unsorted lists and create a sorted list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue

I was given a two arraylists which were unsorted and have a single sorted list. I was not allowed to sort the first two lists.

I just dumped both lists in the priority queue and pulled the values out and put it into the third list. Like..

```
public static void sortList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add(10);
        l1.add(11);
        l1.add(8);
        l1.add(15);
        l1.add(2);

        ArrayList<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        l2.add(11);
        l2.add(2);
        l2.add(15);
        l2.add(18);

        PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            queue.add(l1.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++) {
            queue.add(l2.get(i));
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(queue.peek());
            list3.add(queue.poll());
        }

    }
```

Is there another way of solving this with better time complexity or space complexity?

Comment: Add both lists to `list3`, and then sort `list3`.

Comment: so same time complexity but without extra space?

Comment: Yes, no extra space. Technically the same time complexity, but the constant factor (and hence the running time) should be lower.

Comment: @am1212, did my answer solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the extra priority queue.

`This problem can be solved using 2 methods:`

**Method 1:**

First concatenate the 2 lists and then sort.

Considering, `Size of list 1 = n` and `Size of list 2 = m`

`Time complexity:` **O((n+m) log(n+m))**

`Auxiliary Space complexity:` **O(n+m)**

**Method 2:**

First sort both lists and then merge.

`Time complexity:` **O( nlog(n) + mlog(m) + (n+m))**

`Auxiliary Space complexity:` **O(n+m)**

**Conclusion:** It is obvious from above time complexities that method 2 is better than method 1, and the space complexity for both methods remain the same.

Comment: I think the question clearly said do not sort both lists before merging..